# Retrofit post array to php file

Tags: android

I can post my data to php file with this code

```
Strint senddata = "apple";
Call<DataResponse> call_datas = apiService.getallData(senddata);
call_datas.enqueue(new Callback<DataResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<DataResponse>call, Response<DataResponse> response) {
        try{
            List<mDatas> mlist = response.body().getResults();
            all_recycler.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(mlist, mContext));
        }catch (Exception e){      }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<DataResponse>call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

ApiInterface.java

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("/test.php")
    Call<DataResponse> getallData(@Query("key") String key);
}
```

but I want to send array list to my php file. 
How Can I send string array to php file with retrofit?
example string array:

```
String[] senddata= {"apple","banana","peach"}
```

Comment: It will be better if you use POST method instead of GET

Comment: How Can I use post method can you help me about that? @sodhankit

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change in your ApiInterface.java file.

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("/test.php")
    Call<DataResponse> getallData(@Field("key") String[] key);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I got this issue when I user your code "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FormUrlEncoded can only be specified on HTTP methods with request body (e.g., @POST)."